# How to use the selected values from the s:inputtransferselect struts tag

Tags: struts2

I am unable to find the attribute which holds the selected value in the case of `<s:inputtransferselect/>` Struts Tag. I referred [to the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/inputtransferselect.html) but I'm still unable to figure out which attribute exactly holds the selected values.

In the case of `<s:optiontransferselect/>`, I was able to get the selected values from the **doubleId** attribute. I am looking for a similar attribute for `<s:inputtransferselect/>`.

Comment: Never used that tag, but I guess selected values will be sent and mapped through name attribute as any other tag... or are you tring to access them in the page ? Then you should refer to the generated code, not to the JSP code

Comment: The name attribute gives me only the last selected value. I am not getting multiple selected values.

Comment: Are you pointing to a List, or a single variable ?

Comment: List, not a single variable. Could you help me with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Inputtransferselect creates an input field, a multi option select list and some buttons to add and remove from the select list. When you submit your form this triggers some javascript to select all of the options in the select list, these options then appear in the list on the java side.

Here is an example.

Your .jsp file:

```
<s:inputtransferselect
                    key="cartoonCharacters"
                    addLabel="Add element"
                    removeLabel="Remove element"
                    removeAllLabel="Remove all elements"
                    upLabel="Move up"
                    downLabel="Move down"
                    leftTitle="Add Character"
                    rightTitle="Existing Characters"
                    list="cartoonCharacters"
             />
```

Make sure that your .jsp includes a `<s:head/>` tag else the javascript required for the inputtransferselect to work won't be available to your page.

To see all available attribute parameters of this tag refer to the [documentation](https://struts.apache.org/docs/inputtransferselect.html).

Your action .java file should contain a list which corisponds to the key and list of your inputtransferselect. To get hold of the values, use the list's getter:

```
public abstract class MyAction extends AbstractAction
{
  private List<String> cartoonCharacters = new ArrayList<>();

  public MyAction()
  {
    cartoonCharacters.add("Popeye");
    cartoonCharacters.add("Superman");
    cartoonCharacters.add("Scoobydoo");
  }

  public List<String> getCartoonCharacters()
  {
    return this.cartoonCharacters;
  }

  public void setCartoonCharacters(List pCartoonCharacters)
  {
    this.cartoonCharacters = pCartoonCharacters;
  }

  public String execute() throws Exception
  {
    return SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

I should also note that in my implementation I haven't got this to work properly - the javascript to automatically select all options on form submit isn't firing so I had to write my own event for this, it's probably something to do with my other on submit events clashing.